# Scatterplot with different coloured points

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

Trying to make a simple scatterplot with twelve points. The points are grouped in three groups of four related to four sites on three land use types. I would like to color the point related to their land use types (residential, industrial, and greenbelt). The scatter plot shows the relation between Shannons H and Simpson's index (biodiversity richness estimates, using vegan). I can make the plot, but can't color the points.

Please see the code below. I've tried variations of this. I've also tried the scatterplot function in `library(cars)`. That worked, but I couldn't custom shape/size/color the points, only had access to the defaults.

```
richness.fig <- plot(H, simp, xlab = "Shannon's H", ylab = "Simpson's", frame = FALSE)
points(richness.fig, "sites", pch = 19, col = "green", select = richcompare$use == "green")
points(richness.fig, "sites", pch = 19, col = "blue", select = richcompare$use == "indust")
points(richness.fig, "sites", pch = 19, col = "red", select = richcompare$use == "res")
```

I do get a scatterplot, but in black and white. Error messages are like the following.

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in a single call to plot().  Just pass a variable to the "col" argument which describes the groups you are colouring by.

```
    richness.fig <- plot(H, simp, xlab = "Shannon's H", ylab = "Simpson's", frame = FALSE, col=richcompare$use)
```

If you want to use the points() function then the first two arguments usually specify the X and Y points to be plotted.  This is why you are getting an error about x and y lengths differing.  So an alternative approach is to still do it this way but pass H and simp as the first two arguments.

UPDATE: custom colours can be done as follows.

```
    myCols <- c("green", "red", "blue")
    richness.fig <- plot(H, simp, xlab = "Shannon's H", ylab = "Simpson's", frame = FALSE, col=myCols[richcompare$use])
```

Add as many colours to myCols as you have factor levels in richcompare$use

Comment: Hey, thanks again. This worked nicely. Is there a way to tweak col so that I can set the colours specifically instead of defaults?